# Get specific firewall rule options

Tags: c#, windows-firewall-api

I would like to get a specific firewall rule by name and see the options it uses (The IP Scope specifically) and compare it to something. Is this possible, I searched online but couldn't find anything.

This is how I am adding rules:

```
INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
INetFwRule firewallRule = firewallPolicy.Rules.OfType<INetFwRule>().Where(x => x.Name == RULE_NAME).FirstOrDefault();

if (firewallRule == null)
{
    firewallRule = (INetFwRule)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWRule"));
    firewallRule.Name = RULE_NAME;
    /* More stuff */
    firewallPolicy.Rules.Add(firewallRule);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside that object firewallPolicy.Rules, you might access and use a foreach loop
to go for each rule you have inside your firewall.
If you want some rule specifically, use linq to seach inside that collection:
Something like this:

var rule =  firewallPolicy.Rules.Where(n=> n.Name == "your name");